# Gitflow workflow to move hotfixes from master to development?

Tags: git, github, git-flow, hotfix

Given a repo with both `master` and `development` branches, hotfixes are branched off of `master` and are then merged into `master` with a pull request (PR) on Github.

**What's the best way to get hotfixes moved from `master` to  `develoment`?**

What we've been doing is making another `PR` directly from the hotfix branch to `development`, but then we're seeing lots of unchanged files show up in the diff of the `PR`. We think this is because the `PR` diff is not showing changed files from the `HEAD` of each branch, but from the *last common ancestor*.

To me, it seems like whatever we do should be done on Github, since that's where the PR/merge for the hotfix took place. With that in mind, I'm thinking that after merging the hotfix to `master`, the next step would be to do a PR/merge from `master` to `development`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: merging *master* instead of *fix* into *development* does not make sense because there is no reason why `git` should choose a different "last common ancestor."

Comment: Yes, but the diff for a PR from `fix` to `development` clearly shows files that were not modified.

Comment: and the diff against *master* does not "show" these files?

Comment: It also shows the same diffs, which I would expect. I'm guessing that this is because we've never merged `master` into `development`, and if we start doing this, the non-changes will stop showing up.